# How to create custom db in postgresql in minikube?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, devops, minikube, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to install postgresdb in minikube environment and access it from my django-app.
This is my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
  labels:
    app: posrgres-db
    type: app-db
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: postgres-pod
      labels:
        app: posrgres-db
        type: app-db
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: posrgres-db 
        image: postgres
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5432
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            value: "postgres"
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            value: "Ssl12345#"
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            value: appserver_db
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: posrgres-db
      type: app-db
```

I want to create custom database named appserver_db,
Any idea on how it can be achieved ??
Do I have to install pgAdmin and go that way?

Answer (score 0):

create a job which connects to the pod and create a database on your pod:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: id
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 20
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres
        image: bitnami/postgresql:11.5.0
        command:
        - createdb
        args:
        - "-h"
        - postgres
        - "-U"
        - postgres
        - DESIRED_DB_NAME
        env:
        - name: PGPASSWORD
          value: YOUR_PSQL_PASSWORD
      restartPolicy: Never
```